# Issue with the microcontroller UART1

Tags: pic

I am using [PIC18F67K40](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj3qca1ydflAhUbeisKHfbIAKQQFjABegQIARAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2FDeviceDoc%2FPIC18(L)F67K40%2520Data%2520Sheet%252040001841D.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2xgP8_1xeuJAK80xMj9Eq1) on my custom board. I have interfaced with character LCD to this custom board.

The problem I am facing is:

When the TX and RX lines of UART1 are left unconnected the LCD is not displaying the desired output.

Should those RX and TX pins be Pulled to low or high internally on the code?

If more data is required to answer please ask.

I am using MiKro C PRO and PICkit3 for programming.

Comment: Are you connecting the UART lines directly to the DB25 and to another device? The microcontroller UART pins are logic level and not RS232. You need an RS232 level converter/inverter. Directly connecting RS232 signals may confuse or even damage your micro.

Comment: UART pins are directly connected to the DB connector.

Comment: Can somebody suggest anything?

Comment: MAX232A is an example of what you need.

Comment: @DoxyLover My question is not clear for you I think. Because of the floating status of UART pins output is not getting displayed on the LCD.

Comment: why are using uart in the circuit

Comment: It is used debugging. We are suspecting that floating states of the UART pins are causing micro controller to missbehave.

Comment: In your question, you state that the system stops working when the UART pins are NOT floating, but rather when they are connected. Which is it? In any case, you need to show us the schematic of your board.

Comment: When the UART lines are left floating, the microcontroller is misbehaving. We connected those uart lines to the uart to the USB module and everything works fine. But we are using those uarts for debug purposes. Problem is occurring when uart  lines are left floating

Comment: This is not clear, you said that when uart lines are left unconnected it works fine, but then you say that problem occurs when uart lines are left floating?

Comment: Problem is occurring when uart lines are left floating. I have edited my question

Comment: I don't understand your connections.  Is the serial port connected to the display? 
 Can you provide a figure?  It would help a lot.

Comment: Your problems sound like a code bug to me.

Comment: You should start at the beginning and work your way up to the point of failure and edit your question to include the results. Does your board work at all without the UART connection (is it able to periodically change some pin state you can check)? Does your code reach the LCD routines without the UART? Can you measure the pins used for comm with the LCD with and without the UART? Does the LCD work with UART connected but with no debug running? Is your board's power (VCC) within limits with and without UART?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to leave RX pin floating. You need a pull-up resistor on that pin, either internal or external. Otherwise, a falling edge on that pin is considered as a start bit. I don't know anything about your firmware, but it's possible that it can be blocked if it receives random characters. Sometimes floating pins are affected by the logic states of their neighboring pins.

Interface ICs like MAX485 or MAX232 often have internal pull-up resistors on these pins. Also, in most cases it's a good idea to add a pull-up resistor on TX pin too.